# Created Partition in SD card is not detecting after rebooting

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk, sd-card, fdisk

In Ubuntu 18, I inserted an SD card, and create a new partition using `fdisk`, then when executed the command `lsblk`, I got this

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0          7:0    0    16M  1 loop 
mmcblk1      179:0    0  59.5G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk1p1  179:1    0  59.5G  0 part /mnt
```

the SD card has the partition, and I mounted to the `/mnt` directory

The next day, when I turned on the system, I get to know the SD card is detected but the partition is not detected, when `lsblk` command is executed, I got this

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0          7:0    0    16M  1 loop 
mmcblk1      179:128  0  59.5G  0 disk
```

The SD card is in Ext4 filesystem

How the created partition is not detected/shown.
How to solve this, thanks

UPDATE: `sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/mmcblk1` when executed, I got,

> e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
> fsck.ext4: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/mmcblk1
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
> filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
> filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
> is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
> e2fsck -b 8193 
> or
> e2fsck -b 32768

Comment: What happens when you remove and insert the SDCard once again?

Comment: Modify  your lsblk, and do `$ lsblk -ape7 -o+FSTYPE` and edit+insert the result. (The filesystem/formatting might make some difference.)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, the system is in remote location, it is not possible to do that, and also I put my program in that partition, if it is not detected, then my program wont run

Comment: @Hannu, I updated the question, could you please check that

Comment: If you wish to keep the contents then I'd do what fsck says, but then the SD-card might actually be corrupt / broken in some way. If you don't mind losing the content, try re-formatting it. What happened; maybe you can `grep mmcblk1p1  /var/log` to see if there is anything else than mount/unmount happening. (note: zcat shows the content of *.gz files)